# Having trouble with strcpy() function in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am having trouble with strcpy() function. The output only shows the first 4 letters. What's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *ch,c[50];
    strcpy(&ch, "lkiop");
    strcpy(c, &ch);
    printf("%s", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your compiler say? You should get plenty of error messages.

Answer (score 3):

1. The `ch` pointer is not pointing to valid memory. Trying to dereference such pointer will invoke *Undefined Behavior*.
2. The type of `&ch` is `char **` and the first argument to `strcpy()` should be `char *`. You need to change the code to

   ```
   char ch[50];
   char c[50];

   strcpy(ch, "lkiop");
   strcpy(c, ch);
   ```

   And also, compiler warnings must not be ignored, unless you really intentionally did something that would trigger a warning, and in that case you can make your compiler ignore that particular warning.

Comment: But, c[50] specifically dictates that it can hold up to 49 characters(without the termination null). What if I don't know how long the string will be? You know, if I take a string as an input and don't know how long it will be, how should I approach that situation?

Comment: Well certainly the solution is not trying to store it in an uninitialized pointer, do you know anything about `malloc()`?

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge as I am new at this. Is there any way I can do it with pointers and arrays only and without using malloc()?

Comment: Thanks for that. What do you think could be the reason for showing the first four letters?